# python write unicode to file and retrieve it as a symbol

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am working on a Python program which contains an Arabic-English database and allows to update this database and also to study the vocabluary. I am almost done with implementing all the functions I need but the most important part is missing: The encoding of the Arabic strings. To append new vocabulary to the data base txt file, a dictionary is created and then its content is appended to the file. To study vocabulary, the content of the txt file is converted into a dictionary again, a random word is printed to the console and the user is asked for its translation. Now the idea is that the user has the possibility to write the Englisch word as well as the Arabic word in latin letters and the program will internally convert the pseudo-arabic string to Arabic letters. For example, if the user writes 'b' when asked for the Arabic word, I want to append 'ب‎'.
1. There are about 80 signs I have to consider in the implementation. Is there a way of creating some mapping between the latin-letter input string and the respective Arabic signs? For me, the most intuitive idea would be to write one if statement after the other but that's probably super slow. 
2. I have trouble printing the Arabic string to the console. This input

```
print('bla{}!'.format(chr(0xfe9e)))
print('bla{}!'.format(chr(int('0x'+'0627',16))))
```

will result in printing the Arabic sign whereas this won't:

```
print('{}'.format(chr(0xfe9e)))
```

What can I do in order to avoid this problem, since I want a sequence which consists of unicode symbols only?

Comment: The last line works fine for me in Python 3. You should be searching for the character in the rightmost part of the line as Arabic is written from right to left.

Comment: Gosh you're right. Thanks! Any proposals for the first question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend to split up your question in two parts: This one (dealing with printing / storing Arabic unicode characters  ), but then rip number 1. (transliteration of arabic <-> latin letters) out and post it as a new question.

Comment: @hmw1001, 80 signs certainly won't map to 26 or vice versa, so you'll have to express Arabic characters in terms of _several_ English (Latin) ones. Also, whenever you need some mapping, you're probably looking for `dict`ionaries.

Comment: All of your code works for me.

Comment: Do you use python2 or python3 ?

Comment: Okay I should have made clear the way the encoding should work. The idea is that tuples of either 1, 2 or 3 latin letters are mapped to one arabic sign, I achieve this by asking for the tuples one by one, store them in a list and then convert them one by one. Now the thing is that in Arabic, the signs differ depeding on the position of the sign in the word (initial, medial, final). Thats why I would need a bunch of nested if statements.

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: As for the transliteration, you may want to look into the [Buckwalter transliteration scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwalter_transliteration). This is a [Python script implementing it](https://github.com/andyroberts/buckwalter2unicode).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`encode/decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) function? for example you can write

```
u = ("سلام".encode('utf-8'))
print(u.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: and to print it to the console later? Is there a way backwards again?

Comment: I completed my answer above @hmw1001

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer but can give you a start.

First of all check your encoding:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

**Edit:**

`sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')` was removed from `sys` module. But still, you can comment what `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns in your box.

However, for Arabic characters, you can range them all at once:

According to this [website](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF), Arabic characters are from `0x620 to 0x64B` and Basic Latin characters are from `0x0061 to 0x007B` (for lower cases).

So:

```
arabic_chr = [chr(k) for k in range(0x620, 0x064B, 1)]
latin_chr = [chr(k) for k in range(0x0061, 0x007B, 1)]
```

Now, all what you have to do, is finding a relation between the two lists, orr maybe extend more the ranges (I speak arabic and i know that there is many forms of one char and a character can change from a word to another).